# 907 ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle

i got 907 ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

```
UPDATE A
SET   DELETE_FLAG = 'Y'
WHERE DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
AND IF (? is not null, B = ?, 1=1)
AND IF (? is not null, C = ?, 1=1)
AND IF (? is not null, D = ?, 1=1);
```

How to use Oracle sql to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF` is not valid syntax. Use `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
UPDATE A
SET   DELETE_FLAG = 'Y'
WHERE DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
AND   (? IS NULL OR B = ?)
AND   (? IS NULL OR C = ?)
AND   (? IS NULL OR D = ?);
```

Or, if you are using named bind variables (assuming you are repeating the `?` bind parameters for the same value):

```sql
UPDATE A
SET   DELETE_FLAG = 'Y'
WHERE DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
AND   (:param1 IS NULL OR B = :param1)
AND   (:param2 IS NULL OR C = :param2)
AND   (:param3 IS NULL OR D = :param3);
```